# How to open silverlight childwindow in new browser

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I Have one simple silverlight application.In that application i have pages(page1.xaml,page2.xaml) and childwindows(ch1.xaml and ch2.xaml).when i click on button which is in page1.xaml it should open childwindow ch1.xaml in separate new browser

and more thing when i click on button which is in page1.xaml it should open page page2.xaml in separate new browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri, "_blank");

Or try,

HtmlPage.PopupWindow(...)